Homeassistant: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
I use a card_mod in Homeassistant to define the color on the dashboard depending on the state of my covers. For instance:
card_mod:
  style: |
    :host {
      {% if states('cover.woonkamer_covers') == None %}
        --card-mod-icon-color: var(--orange-color);
      {% elif states('cover.woonkamer_covers') == 'closing' %}
        --card-mod-icon-color: var(--yellow-color);
      {% elif state_attr('cover.woonkamer_covers', 'current_position') > 90 %}
        --card-mod-icon-color: var(--grey-color);
      {% elif state_attr('cover.woonkamer_covers', 'current_position') == 10 %}
        --card-mod-icon-color: var(--red-color);
      {% elif state_attr('cover.woonkamer_covers', 'current_position') == 0 %}
        --card-mod-icon-color: var(--red-color);
      {% else %}
        --card-mod-icon-color: var(--yellow-color);
      {% endif %}
    }

This works perfect although I receive an error message in the logs, stating: "Homeassistant: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'"
Is there anyway to fix this?
It seems it has something to do with the fact that Python doesn't define the percentage as an integer and I should convert it to an int first.
How can I fix this?

This means that state_attr('cover.woonkamer_covers', 'current_position') sometimes returns None rather than a number. Either figure out why it's not returning a number and fix that, or add a check for that.

@Barmar, thanks for the suggestions. I've tried to fix it by adding:
{% if states('cover.xxxx') == 'None' %}
--card-mod-icon-color: var(--orange-color);
But this doesn't help.

None is not a string, it shouldn't be quoted.

That's true, my mistake...but even without the quotes it doesn't work.

Did you put that condition first? It has to be before any of the conditions that try to use < or >.

I realize that so that's what I did. I've changed the code of my first post with the new code block.

You are testing if states('cover.woonkamer_covers') is None but that doesn't guard you from state_attr('cover.woonkamer_covers', 'current_position') being None.

OMG, how stupid :-) You're right..thanks for your time and input..this fixed it!
Thanks to @Barmar as well for pointing me in the right direction!
